# Exporting a single tree svn structure with all history into a new mutitree structure

Tags: svn

We currently have an svn server where everything is in one big tree, for all our projects.

Is is possible in some way to export these projects and their history into a new multi tree structure?

Is there some way to only dump a partial path of the tree so i can get each project in its own backup file and import those into the new svn server?

edit: to clarify, we have one repository with a structure containing customers and their projects, we now want one repository for each project, instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at [Migrating Repository Information Elsewhere](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate) section of the SVN book.  To summarize:

- `svnrdump dump` the repository subdirectory into a dump file.
- `svnrdump load` it into new repository.

[This section](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering) might also solve your problem..