# Move revisions history of a Subversion folder to a new project

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have a few softwares sharing the same Subversion repository project. They share revision count, etc.

I wanna create new projects for each software, but I don't wanna lose their revisions history, used to see logs, diffs, blame, etc.

Is it possible to take a given folder, with its subfolders and files, and move its revisions history into a blank project?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753630/exporting-a-single-tree-svn-structure-with-all-history-into-a-new-mutitree-struc/14754343#14754343

Comment: No problem! Hope it works for you.